# How to increment progress bar during image upload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have the following html

```
 <div class="progress">
     <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have the jquery as......

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    //.....something here
    progress: function(e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    },
});
```

I want to display total percent and some animation(which should increment based on file upload) but unable to fix the stuff. I referred the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/2415/)**  and I tried doing the same but end up with no solution. Any suggestions or answers highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: your selector #progress .bar does not match any elements in the html snippet. There is not an element with ID=progress  or an element with class "bar" a try using the selector ".progress-bar"

Comment: have you referred bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did is just replaced the Html with the following one...

```
  <div id="progress" class="progress progress-striped active" style="float:left; margin-left:30px;" >
  <div class=" bar progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
  </div>
  <div id="divStatus"></div>
```

and then within fileupload...

```
progressall: function (e, data) {               
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').text(progress + '%');               
            $('#progress .bar').width(progress);
            progress == 100 ? $('#progress .bar').css('animation', 'progress-bar-stripes 0s linear infinite') : $('#progress .bar').css('animation', 'progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite');
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this code --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Files using XMLHttpRequest - Minimal</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function fileSelected() {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
        if (file) {
          var fileSize = 0;
          if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
          else
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

          document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
          document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
          document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        }
      }

      function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "next.php");
        xhr.send(fd);
      }

      function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
          document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
      }

      function uploadComplete(evt) {
        /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
        alert(evt.target.responseText);
      }

      function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
      }

      function uploadCanceled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();"/>
    </div>
    <div id="fileName"></div>
    <div id="fileSize"></div>
    <div id="fileType"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="progressNumber"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A description of this code would increase the overall quality of this post